# Как получить ссылки на объекты загруженные в другом процессе (C#)?

Tags: c#, winapi, рефлексия

Есть программа, которая поддерживает систему плагинов.
Плагин загружается в отдельный процесс.
Я хочу с помощью плагина встроить свою функциональность в окна основной программы. Загвоздка в том, что я не могу получить ссылки на объекты программы в интересующем меня окне.
Код:

```
Control MainWin = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
```

... ничего не дает, т.к. MainWin = null.
Попробовал через WinAPI получить хотя бы типы окон процесса программы:

```
MainWindowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;
TreeNode node;
treeView1.BeginUpdate();
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
checkBox1.Enabled = false;
EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc((hWnd, lParam) =>
{
    if (lParam != IntPtr.Zero && hWnd != lParam)
        return true;
        if (!checkBox1.Checked || IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        {
             node = new TreeNode(string.Format("{0:X8} \"{1}\" {2}",
               hWnd.ToInt32(), GetWindowText(hWnd), GetWindowClass(hWnd)));
             AddChildWindow(hWnd, node);
             treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
        return true;
   }), MainWindowHandle);
checkBox1.Enabled = true;
treeView1.EndUpdate();
```

Получил вот такой результат:

[image]

**Что это за классы такие: WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.329445b_r12_ad1 ?**
**И как из них получить объекты типа Control?**
**Или может кто знает как эти объекты получить применяя рефлексию?**
В идеале же нужно получать объекты загруженные в главной программе и использовать их.

Заранее спасибо всем.

Comment: `Control.FromHandle` работает только с контролами у вашем процессе. Грузить плагин в отдельный процесс не очень хорошая идея. Вам придется писать очень много запутанного кода для межпроцессного взаимодействия.

Comment: Программа позволяет загрузить плагин либо в отдельный процесс, либо в отдельный домен. Вы думаете с доменами будет проще?